# thymeleaf select backgound color

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I have the following HTML:

```
<select  
        th:field="*{status.health}" 
        th:value="${status.health}"
        th:class="health_color"                                 
        th:name="status_health">
    <option value="-1">Select Health</option>
    <option th:class="health_color" th:value="green" th:text="green"></option>
    <option th:class="health_color" th:value="yellow" th:text="yellow"></option>
    <option th:class="health_color" th:value="red" th:text="red"></option>
</select>
```

And the following JavaScript

```
$('.health_color').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 'red') {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#ff5050');
    } else if ($(this).text() == 'yellow') {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#ffd24d')
    } else if ($(this).text() == 'green') {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#80ffaa')
    }
});
```

The styles above show up in all the other elements of the page, including the select options, but not the select box itself. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the function is expecting to read the color from a text property, which the `select` field doesn't have.

My best guess is that when `$(this).text()` run for the `select`, it returns the combined properties of all the text properties inside.

Below is a code snippet testing my theory.

Remember that you can always debug your code using chrome developer tools (for instance), it may give you a better insight on what's going on with it.

```js
$('.health_color').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
    if ($(this).text() == 'red') {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#ff5050');
    } else if ($(this).text() == 'yellow') {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#ffd24d')
    } else if ($(this).text() == 'green') {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#80ffaa')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="health_color"                                 
        name="status_health">
    <option value="-1">Select Health</option>
    <option class="health_color" value="green" text="green">green</option>
    <option class="health_color" value="yellow" text="yellow">yellow</option>
    <option class="health_color" value="red" text="red">red</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Assuming that is the case, what property would I read from for the select?

Comment: If you want to change the color of the select input according to the selected option you could try to read the .val() of the input instead of the text(). Also, bare in mind that if the input have nothing selected, no color will be apply. So If you run the function only on startup, the color of the input won't change even thou you later select an option. You may need to re run the function when the select change.